# Categorical Survey Analysis - data structure problems

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to run a probability table for an entire survey. I want to then export these statistics into a csv where each column represents a single question. Each question in my original is its own column, like so:

```
print(InternalSurveyPercent)

Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
1  3  2  Mazda
2  3  4  Ford
3  5  2  Toyota
9  3  2  Hyundai
```

I'd like the results to look like this, but for each column.

```
InternalSurveyPercent$Q1 

Q1
1  25%
2  25%
3  25%
4  0%
5  0%
9  25%
```

I use this function to generate the list (is lapply the right way to do this?)

```
InternalSurveyPercent = lapply(InternalSurvey, function(x) prop.table(table(x)))
```

Then I multiply by 100 because it makes graphic my data easier.

```
InternalSurveyPercent = sapply(InternalSurveyPercent, "*", 100)
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here. I'm very confused about how the data is being structured at this point.

```
str(InternalSurveyPercent)

List of 4
$ Q1: table [1:5(1d)] 25.00 25.00 25.00 0.00 0.00 25.00
..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
.. ..$ x: chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

Why is it returning a list? Why not a data frame with 4 variables (columns)? Thoughts on where I am going wrong/getting lost?

Thank you!

Comment: It returns a list because `sapply` returns either a vector, matrix, or list depending on the simplification of it's result.  It will never return a data frame

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven. What should I use instead?

Answer (score 1):

Seems folks are having different interpretation on the output, suggest to re-frame the question and desired output with clarity.  Anyhow, here s a `data.table` solution based on how far I understand the question.

```
# the data
df <- read.table(text="Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
1  3  2  Mazda
2  3  4  Ford
3  5  2  Toyota
9  3  2  Hyundai", header=T, as.is=T)

library(data.table)
# one liner to get the %
setDT(df)[,lapply(.SD, function(x) prop.table(table(x))*100)][]
#    Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
# 1: 25 75 75 25
# 2: 25 25 25 25
# 3: 25 75 75 25
# 4: 25 25 25 25

# If you prefer stitch the result table with the original together, you could:
df2 <- setDT(df)[,lapply(.SD, function(x) prop.table(table(x))*100)]
df[,paste0("Q",(1:4),"%") := df2[,1:4,with=FALSE], with=FALSE][]
#    Q1 Q2 Q3      Q4 Q1% Q2% Q3% Q4%
# 1:  1  3  2   Mazda  25  75  75  25
# 2:  2  3  4    Ford  25  25  25  25
# 3:  3  5  2  Toyota  25  75  75  25
# 4:  9  3  2 Hyundai  25  25  25  25
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful. I am guessing that you have six options in Q1-3 (i.e., 1,2,3,4,5,and 9). But, Q4 is a different question in that there may not be the same options. Therefore, you will see ten options in the outcome.

```
devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")
library(tidyr)

# I am following your idea with data provided by @LyzandeR
ana <- lapply(InternalSurvey, function(x) prop.table(table(x)))

bob <- data.frame(t(unnest(lapply(ana, as.data.frame.list))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
bob <- replace(bob, is.na(bob), 0)
colnames(bob) <- gsub("X", "Q", colnames(bob))

#          Q1   Q2   Q3   Q4
#X1      0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00
#X2      0.25 0.00 0.75 0.00
#X3      0.25 0.75 0.00 0.00
#X9      0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00
#X5      0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00
#X4      0.00 0.00 0.25 0.00
#Ford    0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25
#Hyundai 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25
#Mazda   0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25
#Toyota  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25
```

Comment: This is the output structure I was imagining! However, I'm getting an error that R can't locate the unnest function. I have tidyr loaded and running. Do I need another package to get this function?

Comment: @ChurlyPickle `unnest` is available in the dev version. That is why I have `devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")` in my suggestion. Please download the dev version. Then, you should have `unnest`.